# android canvas background image

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap

hello am making a simple game for android using canvas and bitmaps i keep reading about how this takes up a lot of the divice resourses but i cannot find the best way for implimetation 
this is the code i have so far please tell me if it is wrong or if there is a better way to do it this is to simply set the background image of the game

```
public SurfaceV(Context context){
    super(context);
    holder = getHolder();
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

@Override
public void run(){
    while(running){
        if(!holder.getSurface().isValid()){
            continue;
        }

        Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
        canvas.drawRGB(0, 0, 0);

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sky);
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, canvas.getWidth(),    canvas.getHeight(), true);

        canvas.drawBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0, null);

        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decodeResources and createSCaledBitmap calls take a lot of resources (memory, cpu). Mpve them out of the loop to be run only once

Comment: thanks a lot by the way do you know the difference between views and surfaces and what is better for a game